# Query Generic List

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, generic-list, generic-collections

I have to log FTP activity using VendorID.
Some vendors have multiple FTP user names, but I only need to log one (the latest).

For example:

- VendorID 1 (two user names)
- Mike
- Pete
- VendorID 4 (two user names)
- Jack
- Luis

So I created a class to store the FTP activity:

```
Public Class VendorClass
  Public VendorID   As Integer
  Public FTPUserName As String  
  Public File   As String
  Public Date As DateTime
End Class
```

- I load the file into a list of VendorClass

**Question:**

How query the list and group by UserID, and return the latest date and time.

**Original List**

```
VendorID    FTP UserName    File                Date
1           Mike            BalanceSheet.csv    6/17/2015 10:20
1           Pete            BalanceSheet.csv    6/17/2015 10:40
2           Ron             BalanceSheet.csv    6/17/2015 10:20
3           Julia           BalanceSheet.csv    6/17/2015 14:20:02 
4           Jack            BalanceSheet.csv    6/17/2015 11:20
4           Luis            BalanceSheet.csv    6/17/2015 09:20
```

**Grouped result:**

```
VendorID    FTP UserName    File                Date
1           Pete            BalanceSheet.csv    6/17/2015 10:40
2           Ron             BalanceSheet.csv    6/17/2015 10:20
3           Julia           BalanceSheet.csv    6/17/2015 14:20:02
4           Jack            BalanceSheet.csv    6/17/2015 11:20
```

My function is only able to select 1 vendor at the time:

```
Private Function FlattenDuplicateEntries(ActivityList As List(Of VendorClass)) As List(Of VendorClass)
    FlattenDuplicateEntries = New List(Of VendorClass)

    For Each vendor In FTPUserNameList
        Dim val As New VendorClass
        val = ActivityList.Find(Function(value As VendorClass) value.VendorID = vendor.VendorID)
    Next    
End Function
```

Comment: You ask for list by `UserId` but there is no `UserId` in your type: do you mean `VendorID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Function FlattenDuplicateEntries(ActivityList As List(Of VendorClass)) As List(Of VendorClass) 
    Dim filtered As New Dictionary(Of Integer, VendorClass)()
    For Each vendor In ActivityList
        If Not filtered.ContainsKey(vendor.VendorID) Then
            filtered.Add(vendor.VendorID, vendor)
        Else If filtered(vendor.VendorID).Date < vendor.Date Then
            filtered(vendor.VendorID) = vendor
        End If
    Next 
    Return filtered.Values.ToList()   
End Function
```

Comment: This line ( filtered.Add(vendor)) gives the following exception: Argument not specified for parameter 'value' of 'Public Sub Add(key As TKey, value As TValue)'

Answer (score 0):

(As this is tagged C# as well, I won't try and translate into VB.)

Something like:

```
var lastByVendor = from act in ActivityList
                   group by act.VendorID into grp
                   let last = grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).First()
                   select new {
                     VendorId = grp.Key,
                     Date = last.Date,
                     File = last.File,
                     FTPUserName = last.FTPUserName
                   };
```

In this I:

- Group by VendorID and do the rest for each vendor
- Get the last record (no `MaxBy` operator in the BCL, so using a sort)
- The `Key` of the group is the value from the group by